# What is the best way to delete a section of a UITableView with static cells?

Tags: uitableview, ios5

Part of my iPhone app displays a `UITableView` with three, static sections in grouped format. However, in some instances (based on user input), it's most appropriate for the last of these sections not to appear when the view controller displays the table.

In the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller, I've added the following lines of code that are executed conditionally:

```
if ([self.formula containsElementWithoutStableIsotopes]) {
    NSLog(@"Deleting section 2 ...");
    NSUInteger sectionToDelete = 2;
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionToDelete] 
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

"Deleting section 2 ..." is logged to the console, so I know that this code is executing, but the table appears to be unaffected: all three sections are displayed as usual.

In the ideal case, I'd prefer section 2 to be deleted before the table view is even displayed, but I could live with it being deleted on appearing. However, if I place the code above within the `viewDidAppear` method instead, the program raises an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` because the number of sections before and after deletion do not match.

I'd really appreciate your help on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use the following code below:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    sectionToDelete = 1;
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3 - numberOfSectionsToDelete;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried that, and it has no effect. As far as I know, `begin` and `endUpdate` blocks ensure that a number of animations in a table view occur simultaneously. As I have only a single animation here, a `begin` and `endUpdate` block is not necessary. Somebody please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: This is because that the viewDidLoad method is executed before the UITableView delegate know about all data that it will use. try to invoke your code in viewDidAppear delegate method.

Comment: i have update my post. I think so you can use it without (beginUpdates endUpdates block)

Comment: you also may get error with a new count of section. please add for example return 3 - sectionToDelete in numberOfSectionsInTableView method; Declare your sectionToDelete in .h file

Comment: Thank you! Your answer worked for me. The important thing was to implement the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method properly. I used another variable `numberOfSectionsToDelete` which I set to 0 initially, and 1 after deletion. If `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns `3 - numberOfSectionsToDelete`, everything works as expected.

Comment: It crashes with exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' because mentally handicapped Apple developers still expect number of rows of deleted section after it was deleted.

Comment: @ruslan try to insert no data row in last section. you can add some conditional that will check for no data row and then you can use insert method to remove this exaction.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is -

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myIndexPath.section];
[myTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:myIndexPath.section] 
           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```